# How can I know who is using my wireless?

Tags: wireless, 14.10

I have a notebook with Utopic Unicorn (Ubuntu 14.10) installed in.

I am suspicious of somebody uses my wireless.

I would like to know if there exists a way to know if someone is using my wireless in real-time.

Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: You can try logging into your router and viewing attached devices. Usually this involves opening a web browser to 192.168.1.1 or 192.168.1.0 and entering in some log-in information. This varies greatly from router to router, so I won't post an answer related to this method without more information as to your wireless network setup (router brand and model, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install iftop.

`sudo apt-get install iftop`

This will install a little package which will let you listen for incoming connections. Of course, this could have its limitations if you are using this to detect unwanted intruders in your network who may be able to fly under the radar. But for the use case where you think a general user is using your wifi or something, this will do the trick. Use iftop as follows (Must be run as root) -

`sudo iftop`

Comment: This will not show people accessing your wifi, just which processes uses the wifi from your own computer.

Answer (score 0):

Once you are logged into the network you could sniff the packets using wireshark or tcpdump.

Even in normal promiscuous mode you will only see data meant for your computer and the traffic itself is hard to follow and most of the time encrypted. However if you capture only ARP packages you will quickly see all MAC addresses and corresponding IP's.

Comment: Since it's his network he should know the password, so should at least see through the wifi encryption. And, If someone clones a "real" / trusted MAC address, I wonder if they could still use the internet, with the "real" MAC silently dropping packets it didn't ask for?

Comment: Yes, he knows and should be logged in, as stated. Lots of the traffic will be encrypted and in standard mode you will not see any communication send between other computers anyway, however ARP is broadcasted so will be received in normal mode. I think it goes a bit too far for this answer to go into detail on how to recognize spoofing. If you look at ARP you will not be overwhelmed with packages and quite simply see MAC vs IP

Comment: But re-reading, the way I put it in my answer can indeed be read in different ways, I'll update it.